# Populate web page using API result directly from API server

Tags: django, api, rest

Firstly sorry if this question has been asked before but I'm a novice so even if it has I'm unaware of the language I'd even use to try and seek it out.

I'm beginning to learn about REST API's and it got me thinking. Is it possible to load the JSON response directly from the API server into the user's browser and bypass your own server?

Imagine you have say a Django app running on a server that accesses email messages from Outlook.com using the graph API.

I assume an ordinary flow would go something like:
User request->your server->graph api-> your server-> user browser.

It seems like a waste for it to hit your server that second time before it goes on to be presented to the user's browser.

Is there a way the Django app can render a template and effectively tell the browser "expect some data from X source, and place it in y location in this template"?

Answer (score 0):

You could do that with javascript. You'd have to include either a script tag in your template, or create and include some static javascript files with the code.

I'd recommend learning and using the [jQuery](https://jquery.com/) javascript library, as it makes what you're talking about much easier to implement. Research ajax requests, those are what you'll need to make requests directly to another server, bypassing your own

Comment: Thank you for your response. That's good to know! Does this technique have a name?

Comment: I think I’ve found what you’re on about. Cross Origin Resource Sharing (CORS). Is this what you meant?

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS

Comment: Close! CORS becomes more important when sharing things like cookies / static files across different domains. It sounds like you are looking to just display some data you've fetched from an API. If that's the case here's [the docs](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/) to jQuery's ajax functionality

Comment: Thanks again. I’ve upvoted but it won’t count it because my rep is so low. I think I was getting bogged down with the idea that the OAuth process would be server side so I was wondering how you reconcile the authorisation “client server” side but provide the information to the user’s browser directly. It looks as though the key is to use an OAuth flow that somehow provides the access token to the user’s browser for the Ajax to make the API call directly. I’ll look more closely at what you’ve provided. Cheers!

Comment: For sure, best of luck!